# How do I generate site map from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, maps

I am new to Php and working on a project which needs to generate sitemaps from URLS which stored in MySQL database. how can I do this?? Is there any one have any idea??

site maps can be in php extension too and only requirement is list of sites display in each page

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very open ended...

You would first need to connect to database,
then depending on what type of sitemap you are doing (google, yahoo, html) You should output accoringly..

What are you trying to produce and what have you done so far?

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply..actually I am creating a website which has a lot of information about traffic,domain,server,geolocation base traffic etc.

what I am looking into is say 100 or 50 urls must be displayed in one page. will give some example please look into mustat.com they do have list of all urls searched in their site.

Regards
Mathew